# Add strings into a java list on cucumber feature

Tags: java, list, cucumber, feature-file

I would like to add the strings that I get in the steps from the cucumber feature to a list (without using `.add` for each string).

e.g., add the following strings in a list "string1","string2","string3"

Also, it would be nice if I can add on the cucumber feature to file more strings, and those will automatically be appended to the list.

I tried creating a table with Scenario Outline but no luck at the moment.

Comment: Use a DataTable in your step -- http://toolsqa.com/cucumber/data-tables-in-cucumber/

Answer (score 1):

Please find below feature file and step definitions. It will take the list of string in the cucumber table and add it to list without using .add.

```
Feature: Get the list of strings from table
Scenario: Get the list of strings
Given Get the strings from following table and print
|Value1|
|Value2|
|Value3|



@Given("^Get the strings from following table and print$")
public void get_the_strings_from_following_table_and_print(List<String> lstStr) throws Throwable {

    for(String str:lstStr)
        System.out.println(str);

}
```

Comment: Its working perfect, I was adding 'Scenario outline' instead of 'Scenario' that's why my test was failing. Thanks a lot!